# How to Check file exists in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a Laravel Controller Function file_fetch()

```
public function file_fetch(Request $request) {

        $file = request('routename');
        $destinationPath = public_path('/folder/'.$file);
        
        if(!File::exists($destinationPath)){
            $content = File::get($destinationPath);
            return view('filefetch', compact('file','content'));
        } 
        else {
            return redirect('/')->witherrormessage('NO such File Exists');
        }
    }
```

This works if i check for file `public/folder/app/index.html` and if i check for `public/newfolder` (newfolder doesnt exist) and hence it executes `else` function and redirects with error message, but if i search for `public/folder/app/` I havent specified the file name, but the directory exists, hence the `if(!File::exists($destinationPath))` function is getting executed!

i want to check just and files inside the directory and even if the directory exists, if file is not present, throw a error message, saying file doesnt exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add one more additional condition to check given path is file but not a directory

```
public function file_fetch(Request $request) {

        $file = request('routename');
        $destinationPath = public_path('/folder/'.$file);
        
        if(!File::exists($destinationPath) && !is_dir($destinationPath)){
            $content = File::get($destinationPath);
            return view('filefetch', compact('file','content'));
        } 
        else {
            return redirect('/')->witherrormessage('NO such File Exists');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix your code by validating the `routename` input such that it will never be empty (and have a certain file extension maybe?)
, which is nice to do anyhow.

If that fails, you can try `File::isDirectory($dir)` which basically calls `is_dir(...)`.

Note that it might give you more control on your storage solution if you use the `Storage::disk('public')` functionalities from Laravel. The API is a bit different but there's a wide range of probabilities associated with it. Read more about that here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#introduction.

Answer (score 0):

If you in different/multiple buckets.

```
//Do not forget to import

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
if (Storage::disk('s3.bucketname')->exists("image1.png")) {
 
}
```